# Can't correctly copy data from one file to another with fwrite()

Tags: c, file, cs50, fwrite, fread

"image" is a pointer to a file from which I want to copy data, and "new_image" is pointer to the directory where to I want to copy data. I do it in a loop, so after each time data is copied from image to new_image both pointers need to update. For some reasons, combination below gives incorrect result.

```
fwrite(image, sizeof(BYTE), 512, new_image);
fseek(image, 512, SEEK_CUR);
```

The entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

BYTE check(FILE *image, BYTE array[])
{
    BYTE holder;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        //printf("%li and %i ", ftell(image), i);
        if (fread(&holder, 1, 1, image) == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (holder != array[i])
        {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }

    fread(&holder, 1, 1, image);
    if (!(holder >= 0xe0 && holder <= 0xef))
    {
        return 4;
    }

    return holder;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover file_name.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *image = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        printf("No such file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    BYTE array[] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff};

    int i = 0;
    int number = 0;
    BYTE m;
    char name[8];
    long images[51];

    while (1)
    {
        m = check(image, array);
        if (m == 0)
        {
            images[i] = ftell(image);
            break;
        }
        number++;
        if (m > 4)
        {
            fseek(image, -4, SEEK_CUR);
            images[i] = ftell(image);
            i++;
            fseek(image, 512, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        else
        {
            fseek(image, 512 - m, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }

    fseek(image, images[0], SEEK_SET);
    //printf("%li\n", ftell(image));

    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
    {
        if (j > 9)
        {
            sprintf(name, "0%i.jpg", j);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(name, "00%i.jpg", j);
        }

        FILE *new_image = fopen(name, "w");
        BYTE example[512];

        while (ftell(image) != images[j + 1])
        {
            fread(example, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
            fwrite(example, sizeof(BYTE), 512, new_image);
            //fseek(image, 512, SEEK_CUR);
        }

        FILE *new_read = fopen(name, "r");

            fseek(new_read, 0, SEEK_SET);
            BYTE variable;
            if (check(new_read, array) > 4)
            {
                printf("GOOd\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fseek(new_read, 0, SEEK_SET);
                fread(&variable, sizeof(BYTE), 1, new_read);
                printf("%i\n", variable);
            }

        fclose(new_read);
        fclose(new_image);
    }

    fclose(image);
}
```

However, if I change the code to this:

```
fread(example, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
fwrite(example, sizeof(BYTE), 512, new_image);
```

where "example" is an (uint8_t) array of length 512, the code works properly. Could someone explain why is that?

Comment: man fread and man fwrite will help

Answer (score 1):

```
fwrite(image, sizeof(BYTE), 512, new_image);
```

This line is faulty. The first parameter to `fwrite` needs to be a *pointer to a buffer* like `example` (which is then written to the file identified by the handle provided as a fourth parameter, `new_image` in this case). What you are trying to do here instead is writing from `image` (which is another *file handle*, not a data buffer) into `new_image`.

`image` does not point to the file data. It is a pointer to a `FILE` struct, which you should never read from or write to directly.

(`FILE` is implementation-specific, but usually consists of some kind of OS-specific identifier -- like the file ID returned by `open()` on POSIX -- a pointer to an optional file buffer that might or might not be filled at any given time, and a couple of data bits for the standard library to determine file position, buffer status, error flags etc.; it is not identical to a file's contents.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what file pointer is? It doesn't act like a regular pointer, because it seems to be impossible to apply pointer arithmetic to it.

Comment: @РоманКирьянов `FILE *` is what we call an "oblique pointer". You never bother with what it points *to*. You also **must not** copy a `FILE` structure around. `FILE *` is what `fopen()` returns, and what you need to pass to e.g. `fread()`, `fwrite()`, `fprintf()`, and eventually, `fclose()`. That is really all you need to know about it; all the rest is for the library implementation to decide.

Comment: @РоманКирьянов I happen to have written a (partial) implementation of the C Standard Library myself, and in the course of that, had to implement [my own version of `struct FILE`](https://github.com/DevSolar/pdclib/blob/master/include/pdclib/_PDCLIB_internal.h#L321). Note that this is just for example; your library's implementation *will* look different.    Bottom line, you should never actually bother with "what it is", and just pass the return value of `fopen()` to the other `<stdio.h>` functions as-is.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just out of curiosity, where did you study so that you are able to write an implementation C Standard Library?)

Comment: @РоманКирьянов Anyone with a solid C background can do it; there's really nothing special involved. P.J. Plauger wrote [a book](https://www.amazon.com/Standard-C-Library-P-J-Plauger/dp/0131315099) about it, which is however outdated (referring to C89), and the code examples are not the most educational I have to say. But it has been useful. As has been looking at other implementations, however I had to take special care there as my implementation is public domain, so no "spying" on e.g. GPL'ed or BSD'ed code. But really, it's not that special. On par with any other library work.